# How to use search by ID with included joined tables

Tags: c#, ms-access

I tried to create a search box guided with 2 radiobuttons which are name and ID
the thing is my code does not work when I try to use search by ID

```
if (rdb22.Checked == true && textBox9.Text.Length != 0)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT PatientID FROM Patient WHERE PatientID LIKE @PatientID;";

        // create connection and command

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, cn))
        {
            // define parameters and their values by opening connection
            cn.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", String.Format("%{0}%", textBox9.Text));
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // execute SELECT, close connection
                    PatientNum.Text = reader["PatientID"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record found");
            }
            reader.Close();
            cn.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
else if (rdb11.Checked == true && textBox9.Text.Length != 0)
{
    try
    {
        string query = "SELECT PatientID FROM Patient WHERE FullName LIKE @FullName;";

        // create connection and command

        using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, cn))
        {
            // define parameters and their values by opening connection
            cn.Open();
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", String.Format("%{0}%", textBox9.Text));
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    // execute SELECT, close connection
                    PatientNum.Text = reader["PatientID"].ToString();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No record found");
            }
            reader.Close();
            cn.Close();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error occured: " + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but _my code does not work_ is not enough to understand your problem. Please [edit] your question adding what error do you receive (if any) what is the expected result and what do you get instead.

Comment: What does PatientID look like in the Patient table, is it an Integer? And it seems unlikely that searching on name does work...

Comment: Ah!, if patientID is a number then using the LIKE operator with a wildcard search pattern likely doesn't do what do you think.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that PatientID is a number on your Patient table. If it is so, then using the LIKE operator with a pattern like this %1% doesn't work. The LIKE operator is used primarily to search text case insensitive or to search partial text. It has no real meaning with numbers.

You need to change your query to

```
 string query = "SELECT PatientID FROM Patient WHERE PatientID = @PatientID;";
```

and add the parameter with

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PatientID", textBox9.Text);
```

Consider also to take a closer look at this great article: [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: thanks a lot! Tbh I don't really know much about programming, thank you for correcting me :)